# Missing Mapping Pane for Agile Portfolio Management in Visual Studio Online

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

In Visual Studio Online, I don't have the Mapping On/Off option for mapping a feature to a product backlog item.  MS says that you do it this way:

http://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/create-your-backlog-vs

relevant screenshot from instruction link below:

[image: Mapping to Features from the Product Backlog]

I do not have that Mapping On/Off option.  Anyone know why?

Comment: FYI - I updated the answer below since we made a decision to move these capabilities down to the Basic license.  Hope you like the change!

Comment: I had the same problem with TFS 2013 (not VSO). Ed's answer prompted me to check the Access Levels in the Web Portal's Control Panel. Indeed, setting my access level to Advanced, instead of Basic did the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Update**:  The [backlog hierarchy features in Visual Studio Online were moved down to the Basic level](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2015/01/27/licensing-changes-user-acceptance-testing-and-agile-planning.aspx) and every account includes five
>   free basic licenses.  This should now start showing up for everyone.

<del>Is your user account assigned a [Visual Studio Online](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-online-advanced-vs.aspx) Advanced user plan or an eligible MSDN Subscription?  At the current time, to access the Agile Portfolio Management features in Visual Studio Online or Team Foundation Server, you will need access to the advanced capabilities by making sure your account is tied to one of the following:</del>

- <del>[Visual Studio Online Advanced](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-online-advanced-vs.aspx) user plan</del>
- <del>Visual Studio Premium with MSDN</del>
- <del>Visual Studio Ultimate with MSDN</del>
- <del>Visual Studio Test Professional with MSDN, or</del>
- <del>MSDN Platforms</del>

<del>Here are a couple of links to help get you going:</del>

- <del>[Assign licenses to users in Visual Studio Online](http://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/assign-licenses-to-users-vs)</del>
- <del>[Change Access Levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159364.aspx) (for TFS/Visual Studio Online which lists all of the features by access level)</del>

[image: Assigning an Advanced user plan to a Visual Studio Online user]

Comment: Thanks @Ed Blankenship. I just have Basic.  I did find the work around of going into the backlog item and linking it to a feature as Link Type: Child.  I'll just have to do that until I upgrade, which should be relatively soon.  I'm diggin' the Scrum process even at the Basic level.  Looking forward to upgrading...

Comment: @hrobertv Awesome to hear!  We're currently working through where features go in which licenses and editions for the next release of Visual Studio so I wanted to mention the question applies for how it exists today.  Our licensing has changed a good bit over the last year so things could change in the future.  Be sure to keep track of the updates on Brian Harry's blog!

Comment: @hrobertv FYI - I updated the answer below since we made a decision to move these capabilities down to the Basic license.  Hope you like the change!